# Check QtKit Dependencies for embedded Player

Tags: cocoa, mono, quicktime, monomac, qtkit

I have an application written in C# with MonoMac, that embeds a QuickTime player, so i want to know:

1. Is possible uninstall QuickTime?
2. If it is possible uninstall QuickTime, this prevents use the QTKit?
3. In case that, the uninstall process will removes the QTKit, is there anyway to check the dependencies for prevent an unexpected exception in the application?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

QuickTime provides a powerful C based API for manipulating time-based media, allowing low-level media export, editing, encoding and decoding. While QTKit is the preferred API for use with time-based media. It is possible to uninstall QuickTime.
Sources: https://developer.apple.com/quicktime/, http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1786, http://www.mightyuninstaller.com/Uninstall-QuickTime-057.html